# Javascript convert mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm(AM|PM) to valid date object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a string representing a date such as "07/13/2015 12:00AM" to a valid date object in javascript. Calling new Date("07/13/2015 12:00AM") yields an Invalid Date.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @devlincarnate Java !== Javascript

Comment: Downvotes without comments aint cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the date parser doesn't like having the AM/PM directly against the minutes/seconds.

Just a quick fix

```
var date = "07/13/2015 12:00AM";
date = date.substr(0, date.length-2) +' '+ date.substr(-2);
new Date(date);
```

Comment: You should consider the advice from @moemen.ahmed and check out  Moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is a function that would turn your datetime strings to 24-Hrs format, and now it can be handled by Date()

```
 function set24Hrs(d){

  if (d.slice(-2) === "PM"){
      var hrs = parseInt(d.slice(-7,-5))
      var mins = d.slice(-4,-2)
      hrs = hrs + 12
      var dd = d.slice(0,9) + " " + hrs + ":" + mins;
      return dd;
  } else if(d.slice(-2) === "AM"){
      return (d.slice(0, 16));
  } else {
      throw ("UNRECOGNIZED_FORMAT","set24Hrs() Received Unrecognized Formatted String");
  }
}
```

So, you can just use like that:

```
c = new Date(set24Hrs(03/1/2015 3:00PM))
// returns: Sun Mar 01 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)
```

Now you have a working solution, however if you have a lot of code to work with dates in Javascript, I recommend to take a look at libraries like **date.js** And **moement.js**

Answer (score 1):

You could strip the date and rebuild like:

```
var timeStr = "07/13/2015 12:00AM";
var dateFormat = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})([AP]M)/;
var dateArray = dateFormat.exec(timeStr);
var d = new Date(dateArray[3],parseInt(dateArray[1])-1,dateArray[2],parseInt(dateArray[4])-(dateArray[6] == 'AM' ? 12 : 0),dateArray[5]);
alert(d);
```